# How to define 'CreateDIB' function or reproduce its purpose in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, winapi

I'm trying to translate this C++ code from **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd938875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** MSDN reference, to C# or VB.NET:

```
case WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL:
{    
    // This window is being asked to provide its iconic bitmap. This indicates

    // a thumbnail is being drawn.
    hbm = CreateDIB(HIWORD(lParam), LOWORD(lParam)); 
    if (hbm)
    {
        hr = DwmSetIconicThumbnail(hwnd, hbm, 0);
        DeleteObject(hbm);
    }
}
break;
```

At first sight seems simple, but I need help to understand about the `CreateDIB` function, I don't know what means and which is the purpose of that function, I can't find info about, and also I can't find it inside the Windows SDK header files, nothing of nothing.

Where is defined that function?, It is necessary to follow good practices in that C++ example?, how to declare it from C#, or which is the .NET equivalent for that unmanaged function?.

I found the **[CImageAllocator.CreateDIB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** which I'm not sure whether it reffers to that, but the parameters of that function does not corresponds to a kind of `CreateDIB(width, height)` like I seen in **[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd938874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** other MSDN code, so probablly is not the same function, and also it is a directshow thing...

Well, this is the current translation I did, it works, but I'm worried about possible memory issues because the lack of `CreateDIB` function or its equivalent managed member:

```
Case WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL

    Dim hwnd As IntPtr = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle
    Dim dWord As Integer = m.LParam.ToInt32()
    Dim maxWidth As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(dWord), 2)
    Dim maxHeight As Short = BitConverter.ToInt16(BitConverter.GetBytes(dWord), 0)

    Using img As Image = Bitmap.FromFile("C:\Image.jpg")
        Using thumb As Bitmap = CType(img.GetThumbnailImage(maxWidth, maxHeight, Nothing, Nothing), Bitmap)

            Dim hBitmap As IntPtr = thumb.GetHbitmap()

            Dim hresult As Integer = NativeMethods.DwmSetIconicThumbnail(hwnd, hBitmap, 0)
            If (hresult <> 0) Then
                ' Handle error...
                ' Throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hresult)
            End If

            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(hBitmap)

        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: `CreateDIB` isn't a Win32 function; my guess is it's a function that calls `CreateDIBSection` and then renders the thumbnail into the bitmap.

Comment: The MSDN article that you linked to says this is a snippet from a larger sample project.  However I'm unable to download the full project, it doesn't seem to be available anymore.  So I'm guessing CreateDIB is just a function that they had written in that sample.

Comment: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples/blob/e8fe83b043727e71f5179da11fc6228475e7973c/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/winutil.cpp#L1632 ?

Comment: You need to go back to the source to work out what this function is. You can surely download the full example and read the code. Do you really need is to do that for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's way too much effort expended to set the thumbnail image. Just keep a copy of the bitmap on your window, and draw it when you need to.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
    static extern int DwmSetIconicThumbnail(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hbmp, uint dwSITFlags);

    [DllImport("Dwmapi.dll")]
    static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hWnd, uint dwAttribute, IntPtr pvAttribute, uint cbAttribute);

    const uint WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL = 0x0323;
    const uint DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION = 7;
    const uint DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP = 10;

    Size thumbSize = new Size(30, 30);
    Bitmap thumbImage = new Bitmap(30, 30);
    object sync = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.thumbImage))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Blue);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.thumbSize));
        }
        this.HandleCreated += Form1_HandleCreated;
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_DWMSENDICONICTHUMBNAIL)
        {
            lock (this.sync)
            {
                int x = (int)((m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16) & 0xffff);
                int y = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff);
                if (this.thumbSize != new Size(x, y))
                {
                    this.thumbSize = new Size(x, y);
                    this.UpdateBitmap();
                }
                DwmSetIconicThumbnail(this.Handle, thumbImage.GetHbitmap(), 0);
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    void UpdateBitmap()
    {
        lock (this.sync)
        {
            this.thumbImage = new Bitmap(this.thumbSize.Width, this.thumbSize.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.thumbImage))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Blue);
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), this.thumbSize));
                //or: g.DrawImage() with stretching specified.
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_HandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr val = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
        Marshal.WriteInt32(val, 1);
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle, DWMWA_FORCE_ICONIC_REPRESENTATION, val, 4);
        DwmSetWindowAttribute(this.Handle, DWMWA_HAS_ICONIC_BITMAP, val, 4);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(val);
    }
}
```

C# since the tags on the question list it.